# When to use SharePoint site/lists and when to use Planner to create projects and tasks application

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, microsoft-planner, planner

We want to create a project management application, with these main features:-

1. Create Plans
2. Create tasks within each plan
3. Define permission on who can view and edit the tasks
4. Create power apps to customize the application UI
5. Create power automate to automate some processes for the app

But I am confused if i should use SharePoint site and lists or to use Planner to implement the above requirements? and why?

Answer (score 0):

1.Can we customize the planner task statuses options, beyond the built-in options?

No, Planner does not support customizing task status options beyond the built-in options.

2.Can we add more columns inside the Planner tasks?

No, Planner does not support adding more columns inside tasks beyond the built-in options.

3.When creating a planner task can we define custom permissions? For example, can we define that only the Assigned To user can view the task or can edit it? and after submitting it, only the user manager can approve or reject it?

No, Planner does not support defining custom permissions for tasks. Permissions are inherited from the underlying Office 365 Group.

4.In SharePoint lists doing the permissions and approvals (as mentioned in point 3) is available, but SharePoint lists can only have up to 50,000 items with unique permissions, so in planner do we have the same limitation of the number of tasks that can have unique permissions?

Planner does not have a limitation on the number of tasks that can have unique permissions, as permissions are inherited from the underlying Office 365 Group.

5.Can we customize the planner interface using Power Apps?

No, Planner does not support customizing the interface using Power Apps.